# can I fix section header view not in the top of UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, sectionheader

We know that a plain `UITableView` will fix its section header view in the top of it. Can we make the section header view not to float in the top of its `UITableView`, but fix in another position, such as 100 points away from the top of its `UITableView`?

Any ideals will be appreciated，thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom view as header to your table view & set the position of tableview from it below 100 points.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry there is no any way to stop it.. But You can do this kind of functionality using the **UITableViewCell**... take the first cell of section to show section detail and set section height as 0..